# Shoulda matcher fails with ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when when testing uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing a Rails5 API and I'm getting an ***ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:***
 error when testing my model associations. Here's the code:

user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_secure_password

  has_many :contracts
end
```

service.rb:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid

  has_many :contracts
end
```

contract.rb:

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :service

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates :service, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

contract_spec.rb:

```
RSpec.describe Contract, type: :model do
  let(:contract) { create(:contract) }

  describe 'Validations' do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:user) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:service) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:service).scoped_to(:user_id) }
  end

  describe 'Associations' do
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user) }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:service) }
  end
end
```

An my tests fails with:

```
1) Contract Validations should validate that :service is case-sensitively unique within the scope of :user_id
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:service).scoped_to(:user_id) }

     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Service(#47073011870820) expected, got String(#47072966778980)
```

I've seem some other questions that look like this but none that had a working solution for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. This only occurs for associated objects that are being validated for uniqueness constraints. I have tried with both the association/relation name (ie `user`) as well as the foreign key (ie `user_id`) - no luck with either of them. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the same issue. One workaround is defining a `subject`

```
describe 'Validations' do
  subject { create(:contract) }

  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:user) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:service) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:service).scoped_to(:user_id) }
end
```

Source: [validates_uniqueness_of does not work when record is new and attribute is an association](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/535#issuecomment-210470765)